# Loading Javascript in Django using the static template tag

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to following the instructions on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/, but I'm running into unexpected results. I have a Django project with an app `dashboard` like so:

```
.
├── dashboard
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180227_2103.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20180227_2304.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── dashboard
│   │       └── dashboard.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── dashboard
│   │       ├── checkin_detail.html
│   │       ├── checkin_form.html
│   │       └── checkin_list.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── my_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

In my project's `settings.py`, the `STATIC_URL` is as it was created by `django-admin startproject`:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The `dashboard.js` file is a simple test script:

```
alert("Hello, world!");
```

I'm trying to use the Javascript in the `checkin_form.html` template like so:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src={% static "dashboard/dashboard.js" %}></script>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

My views inherit from Django's generic view classes:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import CheckIn


class CheckInCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = CheckIn
    fields = '__all__'


class CheckInUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = CheckIn
    fields = '__all__'
```

However, when I navigate to the URL rendered by that view, I don't see an alert with "Hello, world!". Can someone point out to me what is wrong with this configuration/implementation?

Comment: What does your script tag look like when viewing the source in the browser?  Does browsing to `127.0.0.1:8000/static/dashboard/dashboard.js` serve you what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it does. Actually, the Javascript does work after a while (as reported in the answer below).

Answer (score 2):

You need more quotes in this line

```
<script src={% static "dashboard/dashboard.js" %}></script>
```

it should be

```
<script src="{% static "dashboard/dashboard.js" %}"></script>
```

When you're developing it's a good idea to open your browser's dev-tools (F12) and turn off caching.

In production you'll need to change the name of the file every time the content changes if you want users to see your changes. You can do this e.g. by adding a version number (i.e. `dashboard-v1.0.0.js`).  There are a lot of tools in the js-world to do minification/versioning/etc. for you.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I found that the Javascript actually does work (without any additional configuration of `STATIC_ROOT`); it probably just takes some time for the browser to 'register' the changes.

Comment: You may find yourself better off doing a hard refresh in future, by pressing Ctrl+F5.

Comment: sorry that's my bad it's a long time didn't use the template and static files now I'm using Angular for a frontend and i delete my answer and sorry for  wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

please review the answer to syntax - usage should be single quotes within the double quotes

```
    src="{% static 'dashboard/dashboard.js' %}">
```

not

```
    src="{% static "dashboard/dashboard.js" %}">
```

this is enclosed within the "script /script" html elements

due to enclosing a string within a string.